# Logic: trying to prove function uniqueness using induction principle

Tags: logic, induction

I'm new to this topic, so I couldn't solve the problem although it seems to be easy:

```
prove using the induction principle that the following function +: N×N -> N is unique:

m+0=m

m+s(n)=s(m+n)

where s is successor operation.
```

I defined the set A as follow:

> m s.t +<sub>1</sub> (m, s(n))=+<sub>2</sub> (m, sn))

And tried to prove that A is inductive (and then add is unique). but I couldn't do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial on using Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What are $+_1$ and $+_2$?

Comment: Prove that $0+0$ can only have one possible value (simple: $0+0=0$ by design).  Then show that if $n +m$ can only have one possible value  then $s(n) + m$ and $n + s(m)$ can only have a unique value.  Then you are done. ($n + s(m) = s(m+n)$ by design.  It could be trickier to prove $s(m) + n = s(m+n)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Most times you have better luck proceeding by induction on the second term (in your case that's $n$). This has to do with the fact that both addition and multiplication are defined in most cases recursively on the second argument. Let $P(x)\equiv\forall m (m+_1x=m+_2x)$. If you don't like this notation just read $P(x)$ as $x\in P$. We have $P(0)$ by the first property of $+_1$ and $+_2$. If $P(n)$ is true we have $\forall m(m+_1n=m+_2n)$ so given any $m$ we have $m+_1S(n)=S(m+_1n)=S(m+_2n)=m+_2S(n)$. We used in these steps the second property of $+_1$ and $+_2$ and the induction hypothesis from which we got $m+_1S(n)=m+_2S(n)\equiv P(S(n))$. So by induction $\forall n P(n)$

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the "better luck" in the first sentence comes from the fact that the given equations about $+$ have the form of a recursion on the second argument.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yes good point I will add that to my answer